# How to user RegEx in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I know how to use RegEx but confused with the result that is coming with my RegEx.

I have one 'Time' string that I have to parse in javascript and for this I am using one RegEx. Code is something like below.

```
var value= "12 AM";
var dailyRegEx = new RegExp("[0-9]{2}[\\s][A-Z]{2}");

alert(dailyRegEx.test(value));
```

Getting "true" in this situation, which is fine but

```
var value= "MON 10 AM";
var dailyRegEx = new RegExp("[0-9]{2}[\\s][A-Z]{2}");

alert(dailyRegEx.test(value));
```

Why "true" for this?

Comment: Try `new RegExp("^[0-9]{2}[\\s][A-Z]{2}$")`

Comment: _“Why "true" for this?”_ – because you have not anchored your regex to the beginning of the string …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MON 10 AM` is matched because you didn't specify in your regex that it should search from the beggining of your string. `10 AM` appears in the `MON 10 AM` so it returns true.

If you want to restrict it to start with your pattern, use `^`:

```
new RegExp("^[0-9]{2}[\\s][A-Z]{2}");
```

It will match `10 AM`, but not `MON 10 AM`.

Howewer it will also match `10 AM FOO`, because there is no restriction about anything after your pattern. To stop matching with your pattern use `$` at the end, so:

```
new RegExp("^[0-9]{2}[\\s][A-Z]{2}$");
```

Comment: And should probably mention `$` at the end to anchor there too.

Comment: You should add the `$` anchor as well, to avoid `10 AM MON`-like matches.

Answer (score 1):

`^` means at the start of the string and `$` means at the end of the string.

They are called anchors.

Use this regex:

```
new RegExp("^[0-9]{2}[\\s][A-Z]{2}$");
```